# pool::dbPool returning Pool object not able to notify connection observer

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use the `pool` package for the first time. I've created a Pool object with the code below.

```
pool <- dbPool(drv=odbc::odbc(),
                   dbname="dbname",
                   driver="SQL Server",
                   server="server",
                   uid="user.name",
                   pwd="password",
                   port=1433)
```

This results in the following warning message.

```
# warning messages from top-level task callback '1'
# Warning message:
# Could not notify connection observer. trying to get slot "info" from an object (class "Pool") that is not an S4 object


> class(pool)
# [1] "Pool" "R6"
```

Since this is my first time using `pool` I'm unsure if it is safe to proceed despite the warning. Can someone with more experience with `pool` share some insight into the possible repercussions and/or causes of this warning message?

I'm able to successfully get data using the Pool object as my connection.

```
table <- DBI::SQL("TableName")

query <- glue::glue_sql("select * from {table}", .con=pool)

dbGetQuery(pool, query) ## returns expected data
```

I'm using the development version of `pool` but I've also tried using the latest version on CRAN, both have resulted in the aforementioned warning message.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error message. A thread on the RStudio forums suggests to update the DBI, odbc and pool packages to the latest versions, which worked for me

https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-use-dbpool-with-rodbc/5609/3